# How can I see removed files using Git?

Tags: git

When I run "git rm" I can see that files were removed in "git status". However, after a commit when I run "git log --stat" all I see is that a bunch of lines were removed from a file. It's not easy to infer whether a bunch is equal to all. I tried passing in the option to show renames but it doesn't also seem to infer removals (one might think of it as a rename to NULL). It looks like "--name-status" will show removed files with "D" but "--stat" will be ignored if both options are passed. How can I get "git log" to show removed files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git log --stat --summary
```

Will give you the diffstat (lines changed) and also mention creations/deletions at the end.

---

Example:

```
commit e0d418054af3755a933805e587a02d2991e98625
Author: [author redacted]
Date:   Fri Jan 13 17:40:25 2012 -0800

    Remove jslint

 jslint         |   17 -
 jslint-all     |    2 -
 jslint.smjs.js | 4270 --------------------------------------------------------
 3 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 4289 deletions(-)
 delete mode 100755 jslint
 delete mode 100755 jslint-all
 delete mode 100644 jslint.smjs.js
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using `git log` with `--diff-filter=D`?

```
--diff-filter=[ACDMRTUXB*]
    Select only files that are Added (A), Copied (C), Deleted (D), Modified (M), Renamed (R), have their
    type (i.e. regular file, symlink, submodule, ...) changed (T), are Unmerged (U), are Unknown (X), or
    have had their pairing Broken (B). Any combination of the filter characters may be used. When *
    (All-or-none) is added to the combination, all paths are selected if there is any file that matches
    other criteria in the comparison; if there is no file that matches other criteria, nothing is selected.
```